# How to check a string contain "\ and delete them

Tags: python

In python, I want to check whether a string contains " and remove this part. For example:
string like: "\"__PRO__\"", I want to check it contains " and get "__PRO__"

Comment: When dealing with escaping you need to be ***really*** careful and specific what you actually have and what you want to achieve, e.g. write proper `code blocks` using `\`` around it.

Comment: I suggestion you to do `find` and `slice` to practice the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `text` is our string, then

```py
text = text.replace("\"", "")
```

should do the trick (it replaces the `"` by nothing, effectively deleting them).

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '""PRO""'
s = s.replace('"','')
```